# React Native. SectionList. How limit items and show all by button click?

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm new in `React Native`. 
I have `SectionList` and show `sectionHeader` with some items. 
What i want to achieve: if there are more than 2 elements in the list, display only 2, and draw the "Show all" button below. By clicking on button I want to show all the elements.

Comment: Can you please post your code, so that your question can be answered easily